# Is adding ./bin a bad idea

Tags: bash, binary

I can't think of any reason why adding `./bin` to my `PATH` environment would be a very bad idea.

I usually create `bin` folders in my projects that I am working in and I hate doing `bin/command`, it would be nice, to have `command` be picked up by bash as long as I am in the directory with a `bin` folder and that `bin` folder contains a `command` executable.

I need convincing :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$HOME/bin`, `.` and `./bin` are usually looked as a security risk.

For the `$HOME/bin` it's the problem of some "cracker" pushing some script (say a script named nano) to that directory, then it waits until you run something like `sudo nano /etc/hosts` to gain instant root access (change the nano to vi, emacs, whatever; the command isn't important, it's the payload it can execute).

For `.` and `./bin`, it is still the same problem: adding an extra program working from the wrong directory.

If those ./bin/command are in different directories instead of /usr/local/bin (the preferred solution for new, local scripts), it's because they do different things; what if you run the incorrect one?

If you name your commands the same way (let's call then update, commit, cleanup, etc) you may be working on a directory, then you get one phone call and change to another for a quick check. After hangup, your brain will try to resume what you were doing and most of the times will forget that quick "cd" you made (particularly if everything on the screen seems to point to the correct directory) and finish running a command on the wrong directory (say that cleanup script that erases all your month work).

It might look an innocent mistake, but they happen every day to many people! :)

A good workaround (or better solution) is to use alias:

```
alias proj1-cleanup=/srv/proj1/bin/cleanup
```

and add on the script the correct `cd` to make sure it runs on the correct directory.

This way, playing with the `$HOME/.alias` to add the various scripts you need, you have different commands to do the different things, and even if someone cracks your browser to create a `$HOME/bin/ls` file or some local user creates a bin/ls file on any directory, those will never be executed, as your path still points to the correct commands.

But hey, it's a personal choice; you are the one that knows what your local risks are and what the commands do.

Comment: I never thought of the `sudo nano $file` catch, awesome work higuita

Comment: Yes, _if_ you do something like that it _must_ come at the end (but beware of typos like `sl` for `ls`). And leave it open as in `./bin` is much worse than `$HOME/bin` or a fixed set of `$HOME/$SOMEPROJECT/bin`, as a miscreant has to crack your account for the last ones (and then `sudo` protection is more or less moot), while e.g. `/tmp/bin` is accessible to anybody.

Comment: If someone else would have gained access to your account, and is able to push scripts to $HOME/bin, then they are most likely able to modify $HOME/{.alias,.profile,.bashrc}. In this scenario you are screwed anyway. so I wouldn't say adding $HOME/bin to path adds any security risk.

Comment: If the ./bin or $HOME/bin is always after any standard locations like /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin, then wouldn't the example you gave of some would-be cracker putting a malicious file there not work as they intended?

Comment: @Mark not everyone puts the $HOME/bin after the standard bin paths, for several reasons, but even if in the last search path, simple things like `sl` (instead of `ls`), `xs` or `vf`  (bad finger position on keyboard) instead of `cd`, `rsymc` instead of `rsync`, `cd..` instead of `cd ..`, etc. Just create hundred of common typos in the $home/bin and sooner or later you will do some typo. How many times do you do a `ls $HOME/bin` to see what is there?!

Comment: @Kotte true, they are mosly similar, but not all shells use the .alias, ,bashrc or .profile... and this is just equivalent for $HOME/bin only... using `.` or `./bin`in the path have away other lever of problems, you do not need the user level access, any user is enough (like in /tmp)

Comment: @higuita fair enough, but then if they have access to your $HOME anyways to put stuff in $HOME/bin, then they could modify your .bashrc and put a custom  path at the beginning of your path anyways and put some trojan at that location anyways.   How often do you check the timestamp or contents of your .bashrc to make sure nobody has changed it?  Do you see my point?

Comment: @Mark i do agree with you, in my personal machine i actually use $HOME/bin... but on work machines... i do not use it, it looks like a unneeded potential small hole. But like i said, that one it's a personal choice. The `.` or `./bin` are way more dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu at least, this is part of the default user profile:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

I don't think it's a problem, but since it's user-writable and could transparently intercept commands, people can be nervous about it. Obviously this is a safer than `./bin`, however.